# Combinatorial Math Equation - Please Explain

Tags: combinatorics

I was picking apples in my orchard and was looking at this interesting math problems on one of the public terminals in the middle of said orchard. I stumbled upon an interesting combinatorial algorithm. The equation I do not understand, as the author did not provide enough details for me with my understanding of mathematics.

The problem has to do with how many paths there are through a grid of N X N size where N is any number such as a 2 X 2 size grid or a 20 X 20 size grid. So for instance there are 6 paths from the top left to the bottom right of a 2 X 2 grid, when only allowed to move in one of two directions. These directions are down and right. There are various ways to determine the answer. With a small 2 X 2 grid it is easy to draw the grid on a piece of paper and draw the routes with a pen. With a 200 X 200 or even 10 X 10 grid this becomes much more complicated and requires some type of math equation to determine the number of paths going only down or right to (0,0).

The equation I do not understand is:
[image]

The webpage states, "In order to determine the total number of paths to any node Ni,j, we only need to sum together the total number of paths to Ni,j-1 and Ni-1, j".

Then the author explains through an example that there are 70 non-backtracking paths through a 4X4 grid.

I have a simple request, **could someone please explain to me how the equation works?** I have high-school and college math experience but am by no means a mathematician.

The webpage I stumbled across and took screenshots of has the following URL: http://code.jasonbhill.com/python/project-euler-problem-15/

Comment: This is from a Project Euler problem.  Why did you not attribute credit and or a reference (URL) to the the Project Euler in question?  And you've wasted your time, (and our time) by discussing picking apples in an apple orchard with a computer terminal ?

Comment: And where did you find the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ey437.png)?  You know...the image which starts with **Claim** and ends after the oversized question in bold?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sequence is being defined in a more complicated way than it needs to be. It is expressing the following fact.

> Assume that your destination is $i$ units north and $j$ units east of your starting point, and you're only allowed to travel 1 unit north or 1 unit east. Then the number of ways to get to the point $(i,j)$ is the sum of the number of ways to get to $(i, j-1)$ and the number of ways to get to $(i - 1, j)$.

The reason for this is that, in order to get to $(i, j)$, you had to either go through $(i,j-1)$ or $(i-1,j)$ (and could not have gone through both). We can express this as
$$
S_{i,j} = S_{i,j-1} + S_{i-1,j}
$$
If we don't know $S_{i,j-1}$ or $S_{i-1,j}$, we can apply this formula again to put it in terms of $S_{i,j-2}$, $S_{i-1,j-1}$, and $S_{i-2,j}$. And so forth. This is called a recursive definition.

However, in order to be useful, the recursion has to stop somewhere, or else we'll just keep lowering the indices forever. So we need a base case where we know the answer without the recursion formula. The easiest one to use is
$$
S_{0,j} = S_{i, 0} = 1
$$
which expresses the fact that if your destination is due north or due east of your start, there's only one path: due north or due east. So the sequence is fully defined by
$$
S_{i,j} = \begin{cases} 1 & i= 0 \;\mathrm{or}\; j= 0\\S_{i,j-1} + S_{i-1,j} & \mathrm{else}\end{cases}
$$
This is equivalent to the author's definition, and much clearer.

So let's try this on the case (2,2). We have
$$
S_{2,2} = S_{1,2} + S_{2,1} = (S_{0,2} + S_{1,1}) + (S_{1,1} + S_{0,2}) = 1 + 2(S_{0,1} + S_{1,0}) + 1 = 1 + 2 (2) + 1 =6
$$
exactly what you came up with.

We can also find an explicit formula,
$$
S_{i,j} = \frac{(i+j)!}{i!j!}
$$
What this says is that you must take $i+j$ east or north steps in some order, and there are $(i+j)!$ ways to order $i+j$ things. However, because all east steps are the same, we overcount by a factor of $i!$ (the number of ways to arrange the $i$ east steps), and since all north steps are the same, we further overcount by a factor of $j!$ for the same reason. Dividing by $i!j!$ corrects for this overcounting of paths, giving the final result of $(i+j)!/(i!j!)$.

Comment: The explicit formula you gave is understandable to me. I can plug in numbers for various grid sizes and come up with the number of paths to the bottom left corner. :) What do you mean though in your explanation, "all the <direction> steps are the same"?

Comment: There are $(i+j)!$ ways to arrange $i+j$ objects if they are all distinct. So if we use the symbols $E_1, E_2, ... E_i, N_1, N_2, ... N_j$ to represent east and north steps, then there would be $(i+j)!$ ways to arrange those. But, for example, $E_1 N_2 E_3 E_2 N_1$ is the same path as $E_2N_2E_1E_3N_1$--we only care about the direction of the step, not the arbitrary index we assigned it. There are $i!$ ways to assign $i$ indices, so we overcounted paths that many times, and a similar thing applies to $j$.

Comment: That makes some sense. I see that in each of your paths you went East 6 times and North 3 times. I am not completely out of the fog though. Do you know of a webpage that can explain it in more detail? I think I understand that the dividend is every possible (x,y) point in the grid. And that the divisor, the columns factorial times the rows factorial, eliminates duplicates. I am still confused though.

Comment: Each letter represents 1 step in that direction. The subscripts are there to keep track of the arrangement of steps. The idea is that if we want to generate all possible paths with 3 east steps (EEE) and 2 north steps (NN), we label the steps $E_1, E_2, E_3$ and $N_1, N_2$, then look at all possible orders we can put those in. There's $5!$ of those. But $E_1N_1E_2E_3N_2$ and $E_2N_2E_3E_1N_1$ both represent the path $ENEEN$, so we overcounted by using this method. The $i!$ and $j!$ then compensate for this.

Comment: Ahhhh :) That makes much more sense to me. Thank-you for all the help understanding this math.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get to point $(i,j)$, you have two options:

1. Go to point $(i-1,j)$ ... and then make one more move right to get to $(i,j)$
2. Go to point $(i,j-1)$ ... and then make one more move down to get to $(i,j)$

There are $S_{i-1,j}$ ways to get to $(i-1,j)$, so there are also $S_{i-1,j}$ ways to get to $(i,j)$ via $(i-1,j)$ (method 1)

There are $S_{i,j-1}$ ways to get to $(i,j-1)$, so there are also $S_{i,j-1}$ ways to get to $(i,j)$ via $(i,j-1)$ (method 2)

So, the number of ways to get to $(i,j)$ is $S_{i,j} = S_{i-1,j} + S_{i,j-1}$

That really is the one equation underlying all of this!  If you get that, the rest follows.

Now, since there is no $S_{i,j}$ for negative $i$ or $j$, we need to give $S_{0,0}$ some value ... and for the equation to work correctly after that, it turns out you have to set it to $1$. One way to conceptually think about that is to say that there is indeed only one 'way' to get to $(0,0)$ ... which is to not move at all!

And where they say $S_{i,j} = 2*S{i,j-1}$ for when $i=j$, notice that by symmetry we of course have that $S_{i,j} = S_{j,i}$ (e.g. there are of course just as many ways to get to $(2,5)$ as there are to $(5,2)$) and thus $S_{i,j} = S_{i-1,j} + S_{i,j-1} = S_{i,j-1} + S_{i,j-1} = 2*S_{i,j-1}$

But frankly, I think they made that equation more difficult than it has to be. I would just stick with:

$S_{i,j}=1$ for any $i=0$ or $j=0$ (e.g. there is only one way to get to $(5,0)$ (straight right) or $(0,5)$ (straight down))

and otherwise:

$S_{i,j} = S_{i-1,j} + S_{i,j-1}$

Comment: Thank-you for the answer. :) I found the other answer more understandable and was able to use it to solve the problem with an equation the author gave. This helped me understand a little more though. Thank-you for what you do on this website.